# Recursive SQL with multiple base cases

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

```
create table flight_costs as
  with
    costs(day, curr, prev) as (
      select 1, 20, 0 union
      select 1.5, 30, 20 UNION
      select 3, 40, 30 UNION
      select day + 1, (curr + prev)/2 + ((day + 1) % 7) * 5, curr from costs
      where day < 2500 and day > 1
  )
  select day as day, curr as price from costs;
```

will return me 4999 rows of data. This makes sense to me cause the base case would be both

```
select 1.5, 30, 20 UNION
select 3, 40, 30 UNION
```

However, I don't understand why

```
create table flight_costs as
  with
    costs(day, curr, prev) as (
      select 1, 20, 0 union
      select 2, 30, 20 UNION
      select 3, 40, 30 UNION
      select day + 1, (curr + prev)/2 + ((day + 1) % 7) * 5, curr from costs
      where day < 2500 and day > 1
  )
  select day as day, curr as price from costs;
```

will only return me 2500 rows as still

```
select 2, 30, 20 UNION
select 3, 40, 30 UNION
```

should be looped through, and returns

```
day 
1
2
3
3
4
4
5
5
6....
```

Rather than

```
day
1
2
3
4
5
6....
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be the UNION is eliminating duplicates.

For example: `select day + 1, (curr + prev)/2 + ((day + 1) % 7) * 5, curr from costs` for `(2, 30, 20)` yields `(3, 40, 30)`; which will yield the exact same results as everything spawned from the initial (3,40,30) on recursive calls.

...but that does make me wonder why the first query only had 4999 rows; it should have had 2500 from the initial 1 row, 2499 from the initial 1.5 row, and 2498 from the initial 3 row. It is possible the 3 and 1 rows' descendants converge, but since that is obviously not immediate the total should still be well over 4999.

**You can use `UNION ALL` to include duplicates.**

Comment: But when I use `select 3, 30, 20 UNION select 5, 40, 30 UNION` as my two bases, the result day would be like day 1 3 5 4 6 5 7 ... which doesn't eliminate duplicates. If I alter data a bit, it doesn't eliminate immediate duplicates as well. This seems very weird. I suppose I missed something important here.

Comment: 1.5 will never yield an identical row to the others since 1.5 + 1 any number of time will never yield an integer; and any integer + 1 any number of times will never yield a non-integer.

Comment: UNION eliminates duplicate result **rows**; it would allow duplicate days as long as the prev or current differed on rows with the same day. `3, 30, 20` and `5, 40, 30` do not generate identical descendants.

Comment: Oh that makes sense to me now! Thank you so much !! :)

Comment: My heavy use of MySQL stopped in versions before it supported recursive queries like this; I am actually kind of surprised it applies the UNION after the recursion.